# Prove $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do I prove that the following summation diverges?

> $$\sum_\limits{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$$

For tools I have the following:

- Absolute Root Test
- Absolute Ratio Test
- Integral Test
- P-Series

I was using symbolab, and Wolframa Alpha, and they both said it diverges using $\mathbb{li}(x)$, and the integral test. I don't know how to integrate that $a_n$, so my question is, is there another way to prove the series diverges?
I believe that the Ratio Test is inconclusive because $L=1$. So any hints? Because if the math is too above my level then I would not be tested on it in school. My worries is that I am overblowing the difficulty of the sum.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles when asking a question, like the one I exemplified for you here.  Have you heard of the comparison test?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $(\forall n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}):\frac1{\log n}>\frac1n$ and the harmonic series diverges, your series diverges.

Answer (score 3):

If comparison test is not available you can use the Integral test.

$\int_2^{\infty} \frac  1{\ln x} dx=\int_c^{\infty} \frac {e^{y}} y dy$ by the substitution $y =\ln x$, where $c =\ln 2$. But $\int_c^{\infty} \frac {e^{y}} y dy \geq e^{c} \int_c^{\infty} \frac 1  y dy=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

The most natural and simplest argument is $\log(x) < x$ as already given in answers.

If you use the integral test, just remember that
$$\operatorname{li}(x) =   {x\over \ln x}+O \left( {x\over \ln^2 x} \right) $$